# How to normalize stock price data

Tags: r, dplyr

Note: Dates are formatted as DD.MM.

I have the closing prices for a number of companies (here: A, B, C) for a time frame (here: Jan 1st to Jan 5th). The df looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("01.01.", "02.01.", "03.01.", "04.01.", "05.01."),
                  A = c(102, 103, 107, 120, 134),
                  B = c(94, 95, 100, 93, 90),
                  C = c(55, 53, 50, 51, 48))
```

The way I want to normalize the data is by using the z-score, so "z = (x – μ) / σ", meaning that for A on 01.01., this would be (102 - 113) / 13.85641 = -0.7938...

How do I apply this to all my observations? I'm guessing with the `mutate` funcation in `dplyr` but I can't seem to figure out how to actually do it.

Comment: With the data given above, I have the mean of A as 113.2 and the standard deviation as 13.66382, so the value on 01.01 of A as (102 - 113.2)/13.66382 = -0.8196829.

Comment: You could also use `scale` as function for z-scoring.

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, I think you'll need to use something like `across(c(A,B,C), ...)`.

Just to offer an alternative method using `data.table`, which will update the table *by reference* ie. there is no need to write something like `df1 <- df1 %>% ...` in this situation.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)


cols <- c("A","B","C")

df1[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x)), .SDcols = cols]
df1
```

```
     date          A          B          C
1: 01.01. -0.8196829 -0.1096817  1.3324198
2: 02.01. -0.7464969  0.1645225  0.5921866
3: 03.01. -0.4537530  1.5355438 -0.5181632
4: 04.01.  0.4976646 -0.3838859 -0.1480466
5: 05.01.  1.5222682 -1.2064987 -1.2583965
```

For more information, see [Introduction to `data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

Update - there is in fact an even easier way - use `stats::scale()`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @diomedesdata solution, your question asked for the `dplyr` solution. I believe here is an approach that would work for your data:

```
if(require(dplyr)==F) install.packages('dplyr'); library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(date = c("01.01.", "02.01.", "03.01.", "04.01.", "05.01."),
                  A = c(102, 103, 107, 120, 134),
                  B = c(94, 95, 100, 93, 90),
                  C = c(55, 53, 50, 51, 48))

df1 = df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = A:C,
                .f = function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}
                ))
```

This would return the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no package is required at all; write a function and `lapply` it over the respective columns.

```
z <- \(x) (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
transform(df1, z=lapply(df1[-1], z))
#     date   A   B  C        z.A        z.B        z.C
# 1 01.01. 102  94 55 -0.8196829 -0.1096817  1.3324198
# 2 02.01. 103  95 53 -0.7464969  0.1645225  0.5921866
# 3 03.01. 107 100 50 -0.4537530  1.5355438 -0.5181632
# 4 04.01. 120  93 51  0.4976646 -0.3838859 -0.1480466
# 5 05.01. 134  90 48  1.5222682 -1.2064987 -1.2583965
```